# How to convert #ffffff to #fff or #fff to #ffffff while asserting the background color rgb(255,255,255) returned by Selenium getCssValue("background")

Tags: java, html, css, selenium, optimization

How to convert `#ffffff` to `#fff` or `#fff` to `#ffffff` for Assertion?

I am using [`getCssValue("background")`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getCssValue-java.lang.String-) from *Selenium* which returns `rgb(255, 255, 255)` which I can split into:

- r -> **`255`**
- g -> **`255`**
- b -> **`255`**

The following line of code:

```
String hex = String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b);
```

Converts *rgb* to *hex* and gives an output as:

```
#ffffff
```

But from the console, the *background* is extracted as **`#fff`**

[image: fff]

So what can be the ideal way either to:

- convert `#ffffff` to `#fff`
- convert `#fff` to `#ffffff`

I have been through a couple of relevant discussions as:

- [Why use #fff color on body?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48735675/why-use-fff-color-on-body) which mentions that the issue is somewhat subjective.
- [CSS: Which is faster for the browser? color:#fff; or color:#ffffff;](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8536473/css-which-is-faster-for-the-browser-colorfff-or-colorffffff) which mentions CSS compressors will intelligently optimize to the #fff version.

But my tests are failing and there is a need for conversion. Any recommendations?

Comment: From my knowledge short hex colors are compound like this: `#aabbcc` -> `#abc`. You can split the log hex into 3 segments [aa, bb, cc] and check if both chars are identical and for short hex, split into [a, b, c] and duplicate them.

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Selenium... that's why I removed the tag. There's not a single mention of it.

Comment: @JeffC Perhaps you missed to notice the entire discussion is based on the output of  `getCssValue("background")` which is pretty much specific to _Selenium_

Comment: Why all the conversions? What's wrong with `Assert.assertEquals("rgb(255,255,255)", e.getCssValue("background"));`? You are going to hard code the expected value anyway.

Comment: The question is `How to convert #ffffff to #fff or #fff to #ffffff for Assertion?`... how you get the value is not consequential to the question.

Comment: @JeffC The question title field is `varchar[150]` only but then we need to keep the title short and sweet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `replaceAll` with a regular expression that looks for the case where all three parts use the same digit:

```
static String getHex(int r, int g, int b) {
    return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b).replaceAll("^#([a-fA-F])\\1([a-fA-F])\\2([a-fA-F])\\3$", "#$1$2$3");
}
```

That looks for a string starting with `#` followed by three pairs of matching hex digits, and replaces them with just the short form. (I suppose I could have just used `[a-f]` instead of `[a-fA-F]` in your *specific* example, since you know you'll be getting lower case only, but...)

Complete example (on [Ideone](https://ideone.com/CieKl0)):

```
public class Example {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(getHex(255, 255, 255)); // #fff
        System.out.println(getHex(255, 240, 255)); // #fff0ff
    }

    static String getHex(int r, int g, int b) {
        return String.format("#%02x%02x%02x", r, g, b).replaceAll("^#([a-fA-F])\\1([a-fA-F])\\2([a-fA-F])\\3$", "#$1$2$3");
    }
}
```

Comment: That was a gem of an idea backed up with a canonical solution.

Comment: @DebanjanB - :-) Thanks. If you do this a **lot**, it may be worth using `Pattern` to avoid recompiling the regex each time.

Answer (score 3):

You could write a simple method that "normalizes" your HTML color codes to short or long format *if* they have all the same hex digits:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(normalizeHtmlColors("#ffffff", true));
    System.out.println(normalizeHtmlColors("#fff", true));
    System.out.println(normalizeHtmlColors("#ffffff", false));
    System.out.println(normalizeHtmlColors("#fff", false));
}

public static String normalizeHtmlColors(String colorCode, boolean toShort) {
    if (toShort && colorCode.matches("^#?([0-9a-fA-F])\\1{5}$"))
        colorCode = colorCode.replaceFirst("#?([0-9a-fA-F])\\1{5}", "#$1$1$1");
    else if (!toShort && colorCode.matches("^#?([0-9a-fA-F])\\1{2}$"))
        colorCode = colorCode.replaceFirst("#?([0-9a-fA-F])\\1{2}", "#$1$1$1$1$1$1");
    return colorCode;
}
```

This would print:

```
#fff
#fff
#ffffff
#ffffff
```

...so you can decide in which direction to transform. If the input doesn't match the two cases, it will just be returned.