# Different CSS results between geckodriver and ChromeDriver

Tags: css, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, capybara, geckodriver

I'm encountering a problem when validating CSS properties in my Capybara tests, each webdriver is returning the selector value in a different format.

In my project, a page contains an element that has a CSS property `background-color` as a hexadecimal value.  A sample of the CSS looks like the following:

```
#selected-colour-red {
    background-color: #ff0000;
```

When the tests run, the webdrivers (for whatever reason I *still* don't understand) instead look for the RGB equivalent of this hexadecimal value.  So, my Capybara tests analyse the input value and convert it to the corresponding RGB value, so that the RSpec matcher can compare it to what the webdriver sees:

```
And(/^I should see the colour "(.*?)"$/) do |colour|
  case colour
    when 'red'
      rgb_colour = 'rgb(255, 0, 0)'
    when 'green'
      rgb_colour = 'rgb(0, 255, 0)'
    when 'blue'
      rgb_colour = 'rgb(0, 0, 255)'
  selected_colour = page.find(:css, 'div#colours-grid div#selected-colour-' + colour)
  pp selected_colour.style('background-color')   # debug - see what property the webdriver returns
  expect(selected_colour.style('background-color')).to have_content(rgb_colour)
end
```

The `pp` line outputs what the webdriver sees when the test runs.

When I run the tests using the geckodriver, the results pass because the value the webdriver sees matches that within the test:

```
    And I should see the text "The selected colour is <colour>" # features/colours.feature:14

    Examples: 
      | colour |
{"background-color"=>"rgb(255, 0, 0)"}
      | red    |
{"background-color"=>"rgb(0, 255, 0)"}
      | green  |
{"background-color"=>"rgb(0, 0, 255)"}
      | blue   |
3 scenarios (3 passed)
15 steps (15 passed)
0m3.205s
```

However, chromerdriver tests fail because the CSS property returned is in a different `rgba` format:

```
 And I should see the text "The selected colour is <colour>" # features/colours.feature:14

    Examples: 
      | colour |
{"background-color"=>"rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)"}
      | red    |
      expected to find text "rgb(255, 0, 0)" in "{\"background-color\"=>\"rgba(255, 0, 0, 1)\"}" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/colours.rb:47:in `/^I should see the colour "(.*?)"$/'
      features/colours.feature:17:13:in `I should see the colour "red"'
{"background-color"=>"rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)"}
      | green  |
      expected to find text "rgb(0, 255, 0)" in "{\"background-color\"=>\"rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)\"}" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/colours.rb:47:in `/^I should see the colour "(.*?)"$/'
      features/colours.feature:18:13:in `I should see the colour "green"'
{"background-color"=>"rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)"}
      | blue   |
      expected to find text "rgb(0, 0, 255)" in "{\"background-color\"=>\"rgba(0, 0, 255, 1)\"}" (RSpec::Expectations::ExpectationNotMetError)
      ./features/step_definitions/colours.rb:47:in `/^I should see the colour "(.*?)"$/'
      features/colours.feature:19:13:in `I should see the colour "blue"'
3 scenarios (3 failed)
15 steps (3 failed, 3 skipped, 9 passed)
0m2.051s
```

I don't want to write driver-specific code as that is difficult to maintain.

- Should I write the expectation to use a regular expression as a matcher?
- Is there a way to alter the format that chromium or firefox use for representing RGB values?
- Is it possible to write the test so that it explicitly matches the hexadecimal value in the CSS?
- Why do the drivers represent this value differently?

Comment: Does [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767206/how-to-convert-ffffff-to-fff-or-fff-to-ffffff-while-asserting-the-background) answers your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to ask the writers of chromedriver and geckodriver why their return values are different, but it's likely because the spec is lax - https://www.w3.org/TR/webdriver/#get-element-css-value - and they've just chosen to return two different, but valid, values.

No it is not possible to match the hexadecimal value in the CSS directly because that is not accessible to Capybara. The best solution is to use a regex, and you should be using the `match_style` matcher rather than calling `style` directly

```
expect(selected_colour).to match_style('background-color' => /rgba?\(255, 0, 0(, 1)?\)/)
```

Another option would be to use the `style` filter for the `have_css` matcher and just do it all at once

```
expect(page).to have_css('div#colours-grid div#selected-colour-' + colour, style: { 'background-color' => /rgba?\(255, 0, 0(, 1)?\)/ } )
```

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't familiar with the `match_style` matcher.  I will check that out.

Comment: Just to confirm, is there a trailing `/` missing from the example?  i.e. should it be:
`expect(selected_colour).to match_style('background-color' => /rgba?\(255, 0, 0(, 1)?\)/)` ?

Comment: @jimjamz Yes - the regex terminator was missing - fixed

Comment: I've simply changed the values in the case switch to be that of the regex:

`case colour when 'red' rgb_colour = /rgba?\(255, 0, 0(, 1)?\)/`

And the matcher:
`expect(selected_colour).to match_style('background-color' => rgb_colour)`

Comment: @jimjamz I've also updated to show the `style` filter available on most of Capybaras selectors

Comment: Thank you for the additional option.  I will now go have a look at how (or if) they addressed this in the `webdrivers` gem.